# Добавление menubar в QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как добавить menubar в Qwidget в данном коде

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(10,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1366,720)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')

menubar = QMenuBar()
menubar.addMenu('&File')
hbox.setMenuBar(menubar)

root.show()
...
```