# Добавление ToolBar в QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как добавить `toollbar` в `QWidget` на примере данного кода пробовал что то сделать сам по примеру [заданного ранее моего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743735/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-menubar-%D0%B2-qwidget), но ничего толкового не вышло.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(10,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1366,720)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Обновил после ответа**  Теперь получается что это немного не так как хотелось бы. Скорее всего делаю что то не так если это так то можете подправить

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(10,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1366,720)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
menubar = QMenuBar()
opentestfile = QAction( 'Открыть', root)
closefile = QAction( 'Закрыть программу', root)
closefile.triggered.connect(lambda : root.close())
fileMenu_file = menubar.addMenu('File')
fileMenu_file.addAction(opentestfile)
fileMenu_file.addAction(closefile)
hbox.setMenuBar(menubar)
tool = QToolBar()
tool.addWidget(QPushButton("Tool 1"))
tool.addWidget(QPushButton("Tool 2"))
hbox.addWidget(tool)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Qt Designer не пробовали пользоваться

Comment: @Александр по мне легче самому писать т.к. хотя бы разбираешь по немногу что как делается чем просто скачать конструктор

Comment: Что-то у вас не видно кода, который вам предложили добавить.

Comment: А почему именно QWidget? Чем QMainWindow не нравится?

Comment: @gil9red просто основа программы построена на qwidget

Comment: QWidget это простой виджет, а ваши хотелки с QToolBar (и возможно QMenuBar) лучше через QMainWindow реализовывать, т.к. он является специализированным на это. Да и в ответе Avernial видно, что по использованию разница между QWidget и QMainWindow минимальная, а попробуйте оба примера запустить и сравнить как будет toolbar выглядеть для обоих примеров

Comment: @gil9red  минимальна т.е. Скорость или в чем разница

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы добавить `QToolBar` на ваш виджет необходимо сначала сделать меню, добавить в него несколько элементов, а потом разместить это меню на `QGridLayout`. 
Вот простой пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        layout = Qt.QGridLayout(self)

        menu = Qt.QMenuBar(self)
        file = menu.addMenu("File")
        file.addAction("Open")
        file.addAction("Exit")

        edit = menu.addMenu("Edit")
        edit.addAction("Undo")
        edit.addAction("Redo")

        layout.addWidget(menu, 0, 0)

        tool = Qt.QToolBar()
        tool.addWidget(Qt.QPushButton("Tool 1"))
        tool.addWidget(Qt.QPushButton("Tool 2"))
        layout.addWidget(tool, 1, 0)

        layout.addWidget(Qt.QTextEdit(), 2, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Пример с toolbar и menubar:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Main(Qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        menu = Qt.QMenuBar()
        menu.addAction("File")
        menu.addAction("Edit")
        self.setMenuBar(menu)

        tool = Qt.QToolBar()
        tool.addWidget(Qt.QPushButton("Tool 1"))
        tool.addWidget(Qt.QPushButton("Tool 2"))

        self.addToolBar(tool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Разве если добавляешь 'setMenuBar' основной меню бар не исчезает? Просто в программе и меню бар и тулбар

Comment: У `QWidget` по умолчанию нет ни toolbar'a ни menubar'a ни statusbar'a. Поэтому ничего не исчезнет. Если вам нужен и menubar и toolbar то используйте `QMainWindow`, либо, если все таки нужен `QWidget` используйте свой layout и в него добавляйте все необходимые меню.

Comment: Добавил пример с toolbar'ом и menubar'ом.

Comment: Ну т.е. Если я добавляю менюбар и тулбар то их помещать в один блок layout? И если это так то в любом случае будет использоваться 'setMenuBar'?

Comment: Если в один layout, то метод будет `addWidget`.

Comment: Через qmainwindows я вкурсе  как делать это, мне конкретно в qwidget, или это так же работает и там?

Comment: Посмотрите первый вариант в моем ответе. Может вам такой вариант подойдет.